# Diode issues in voltage dropoff

Tags: diodes

I've been wondering if there is any way to eliminate voltage drop in a diode?

If there is not, what could I use to replace the function of the diode without any voltage decrease?

Comment: I've heard of diodes made from unobtainium that do this.

Comment: @Andyaka I was reading about some diodes from a company called "Ideal" than do this as well.

Comment: They're probably made of that stuff.

Comment: No, but see if you can figure it out. When you do make a diode with no resistance, I have a pile of money waiting for you.

Comment: Ignore the rude and idiotic comments - most seem to be from people who have lost all knowledge of electronics in the new year. With some extra components you can arrange for a MOSFET to turn on when you require diode conduction. While zero loss is not practical, very low loss is achievable. For example a MOSFET with on resistance of 1/1000th of an Ohm when on, will pass 10 Amps with a loss of 0.1 Watts. That is very small compared to the energy used overall in most circuits. eg if the system is 12V based then 0.1V drop loses about 0.8% of the total power.

Comment: You should specify what you are trying to actually achieve, what current?, wjhat system voltage? What purpose?

Comment: @Fake: Actually I care.  It's relevant information showing that the OP is being a arrogant ingrate.  After seeing your comment, I looked at the edit history.  Since the OP didn't fix this himself, I'm going to -1 this and vote to close.  Too bad Russell made it impossible for the OP to redeem himself.  It means nothing when the disrespect is removed by a third party.

Answer (score 3):

Look for "Active diode" circuits that use a FET for the series element.  These can have very low voltage drop.

Comment: Is there any way to have no drop?

Comment: No, nothing has no drop unless you can cool it to near absolute zero.  (Or maybe a little higher for certain alloys.)

Comment: @OskarSkog No, I was saying that NOTHING has no drop unless it's a superconductor.  I wasn't implying that there could be no-drop diodes at low temperatures.  Though see Spehro's comment below.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing under room temperature conditions. You can make an almost perfect signal rectifier - supplying a voltage from an external power supply that mimics a rectified version of the input voltage. You can also switch a very low resistance device such as a large MOSFET, but it will still have some resistance and thus some drop if current is flowing.

There is also physics-experiment type asymmetric behavior possible in certain superconducting structures at < 2K, but that's not exactly practical. See for example [Controllable Disorder in a Hybrid Nanoelectronic System: Realization of a Superconducting Diode](http://www.nature.com/articles/srep02274)  in Nature. The paper does not describe a working device, only an avenue that may be followed to develop such a device in the future.